# Log File Rotation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, log-rotation

I am working on a website in Ruby on Rails and have enabled log rotation on the server with the reference of [blog article](http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/10/rotating-rails-log-files/#more-24).

I have written the following code in my **/etc/logrotate.conf** file.

```
/path/to/your/rails/applicaton/log/*.log {
  daily
  missingok
  rotate 7
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  copytruncate
}
```

But I still happen to get this error once in 2 weeks:

```
Errno::ENOSPC: No space left on device - <STDERR>
```

In this case I have to remove the log files manually which is a cause of worry. I have rechecked my settings.

Please suggest why this issue comes even after **rotating log daily** or how I can I rotate my logs **more frequently** or any better way to escape this error.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Is `rotate 7` config working as expected? i.e. are only last 7 days' log file copies kept at any point in time?

Comment: I just checked the log files count. Its more than 7. Why is it so?

Comment: Could be a rights issue on the log directory; check if the user running the `/usr/sbin/logrotate` binary is able to delete files in this folder.